# Add clear button inside input component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components

I'm trying to add a clear text button inside an Input component, but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

This is the closest I managed, but it's not quite right.

[You can see the clear text icon "X" shorten the input container.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MtM1.png)

[It's suppose to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34HRt.png)

```
<Block row noflex space="between" paddingLeft="2x">
  <Input
    flex
    value={search}
    iconLeft="search"
    radius={SIZES.base / 2}
    style={styles.search}
    selectionColor={COLORS.white}
    iconStyle={styles.searchIcon}
    containerStyle={styles.searchContainer}
    color={Utils.rgba(COLORS.white, 0.3)}
    onFocus={() => onSearch()}
  />
  <Button 
    flex={0}
    color="transparent" center middle
    style={styles.clearIconStyle}
    onPress={() => setFilters({...filters, address: '', lat: gps.latitude, lng: gps.longitude })}
  >
  <Icon name="clear" />
 </Button>
</Block>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 right: SIZES.width * 0.07,
 bottom: SIZES.height * 0.003
}
```

Any suggestions of how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can create a view with flex direction row and add buttons to the left and right of textinput, then clear the textinput state when cross button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

**Below on the very bottom is what I did and you can elaborate on it to make the picture.**

This is the code below, but basically what you do is you make a view a linear gradient. And then inside make another view with a 'transparentish' background color.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { View, Text,Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import MaskedView from '@react-native-community/masked-view';
import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';
const {width,height} = Dimensions.get("window");
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 
import { Entypo } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

const MaskScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center"}}>
           

        {/* Gradient block */}
        <LinearGradient
        // Background Linear Gradient
        colors={["purple","cyan","blue"]}
        style={{width:width*.85,height:height/12,flexDirection:'row'}}
        >
            <View style={{flex:10,margin:10,borderRadius:5,backgroundColor:'rgba(219, 229, 255, 0.8)',flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between',padding:10,alignItems:"center"}}>
                <FontAwesome name="search" size={30} color="black" />
                <Entypo name="cross" size={30} color="black" />
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1}}>

            </View>
            
        </LinearGradient>
            
        </View>
    )
}

export default MaskScreen
```

[image]